# Can you do anything with the "gross food" in the garbage dump by the Ishto Sah Shrine?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

When exploring the gerudo desert, I found this garbage dump with a shrine, but this woman is cooking an over burnt piece of meat, and when I try to get it, she tells me to not touch it. What do I do with that? Is it just a meme or something?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Game play wise, trying to take [Moza's](https://zelda-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Moza) food doesn't serve much of a purpose other than dialogue. However, if you talk to her directly, she will provide you with recipes for [Dubious Food](https://zelda-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Dubious_Food) and [Rock Hard Food](https://zelda-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Rock-Hard_Food) that heal additional health than their standard forms would.

Comment: Moza is mostly just there for entertainment value. Her garbage dump is *so* far out of the way that, by the time you find her, you've almost certainly got a decent supply of hearty food (which always heals at least as much as any other food, since it fully restores your red hearts).

Comment: Correction: Rock-Hard Food always restores 1/4 of a heart. I guess Moza's Rock-Hard Food recipe is a scam :)